# Entity Framework LINQ calling switchoffset() function

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table with one of the columns is a datetimeoffset type. I am using EF Core, how do I call the sql built-in function switchoffset()? I have the user's timezone value already, but don't know how to call this function to convert the datetimeoffset value to user's own time.

I tried "SqlFunctions" and there is no such function available.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured a way of doing this. I would help alot if you find a solution and post

Comment: No, I have not figured it out. I am using .NET function now to convert the value.

Comment: Like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0/#database-scalar-function-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Add custom/built-in functions in a static class

```
    public static class CustomFunctions
    {
        public static DateTime ChangeTimeZoneOffset(this DateTime datetime, string timeZoneOffset)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public static DateTime ChangeTimeZoneOffset(this DateTime datetime, int timeZoneOffset)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public static string Format(this DateTime datetime, string format)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public static string Format(this DateTime datetime, string format, string culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

#### 2. Map those functions correctly:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(CustomFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(CustomFunctions.ChangeTimeZoneOffset), new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(string) }))
                .HasName("SwitchOffset").IsBuiltIn();

modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(CustomFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(CustomFunctions.ChangeTimeZoneOffset), new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(int) }))
                .HasName("SwitchOffset").IsBuiltIn();

modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(CustomFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(CustomFunctions.Format), new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(string) }))
                .HasName("Format").IsBuiltIn();

modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(CustomFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(CustomFunctions.Format), new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(string), typeof(string) }))
                .HasName("Format").IsBuiltIn();
```

#### 3. Use it in your LINQ:

```
    ...
    .Select(i => new
    {
        TheDateTimeInUserTimeZone = CustomFunctions.ChangeTimeZoneOffset(i.MyDateTime, timeZoneOffsetVariable)
    }
```

---

*If your time zone offset is static (eq your user country is static but datetimes are stored in UTC)*, One solution is using Computed Column:

```
entity.Property(e => e.TheDateTimeInIRIran).HasComputedColumnSql("(SWITCHOFFSET([MyDateTime], '+03:30'))", false);
```

also you can convert date from greg to jalali for example:

```
entity.Property(e => e.TheDateTimeInIRIran).HasComputedColumnSql("(FORMAT(SWITCHOFFSET([MyDateTime], '+03:30'), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'fa-ir'))", false);
```

or use `At Time Zone` clause (SQL Server 2016+) supporting daylight saving time.