# SQL - Does anyone know to translate this query statement in Linq? I tried but I always get translation error

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, datetimeoffset

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @dto1 datetimeoffset;
SET @dto1 = '2023-03-24 00:00:00.0000000 -02:00';



SELECT JOB.JobId, JOB.NextExecutionUTC
FROM ATS.Job AS Job
WHERE JOB.StatusId = 1
AND JOB.LastRunState IS NULL
AND CONVERT(date, SWITCHOFFSET(JOB.NextExecutionUTC, DATEPART(tz, @dto1))) = CONVERT(DATE,@dto1)
```

I tried in Linq but always when I try to change the offset of the column that it is datetimeoffset it returns me a "translation" error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see a function mapping for SWITCHOFFSET or any other timezone transformation in EF 6, so it may not be possible. I see a function added in EF Core 7.

Comment: It appears that SWITCHOFFSET is not a supported function, even when using the [SqlFunctions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions?view=netframework-4.8.1). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689587/entity-framework-linq-calling-switchoffset-function). The answer there covers defining a custom function mapping that might solve your problem.

Comment: Another approach would be to calculate the timezone offset in minutes using `dto1.Offset.TotalMinutes` and then use the canonical `AddMinutes()` function in your LINQ query to adjust `NextExecutionUTC`.

Comment: Perhaps better than either of the above would be to calculate the start and end of the local dto1 date/time as UTC date/times on the application side `DataTime StartUtc = dto1.Date.ToUniversalTime(); DataTime EndUtc = StartUtc.AddDays(1);` and then test for that date/time range in the LINQ query `.Where(job => job.NextExecutionUTC >= StartUtc && job.NextExecutionUTC < EndUtc)`. Note that the end date/time comparison is exclusive. One big advantage to this approach is that an index on NextExecutionUTC can be used to efficiently filter the data.

Comment: The issue is that I need every job on the specific date (dto), I don't take into consideration the time for NextExecutionUTC, only for dto. And dto and NextExecutionUTC are n diffrent timezones. The NextExecutionUTC timezone is not fixed.

Comment: "NextExecutionUTC timezone is not fixed"? Are you saying that NextExecutionUTC is not always a UTC time?

Comment: it is an datetimeoffset with different offsets

Comment: it worked with what proposed @TN. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI - SQL Server's `datetimeoffset` type will always query using UTC equivalents.  It doesn't matter offset is stored.